# Next js 13 the parameters of Api Routes basically the response parameter (App Directory)

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I want to write a NextJS API where after performing a series of calculations I have access to the res parameter like express.js.
My main intention is to call res.send to return a script and execute that script, which I did in the previous program I wrote.

my previous code was something like this:

```
const apiService = async (req, res) => {
.
.
.
   res.send(`
        <script>
          localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(${somevalue}));
         window.location.href = "${redirecttosomewhere}";
      </script>`);
}
```

and now in my next js app i have this NextResponse which just have some limited methods for usage

```
export async function POST(req, res) {
// nothing as the res
}
```

how can i use this method res.send in next.js app does it need to install the express js
thank you for guidances

Comment: You can use `res.status(200).send(whatever response you want)`

Comment: its not as simple as you respond
error - TypeError: res.status is not a function
res is not a parameter of new next js Api routes

Comment: It should work, even in their docs you can see it https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes

Comment: the 13 version is different my friend in last versions of next js you've accessed the req , res but in the app directory the res is not accessible

Comment: I think your question is not clear on what you want to achieve

Comment: i think you didnot read the question in correct way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255858/discussion-between-soheil-bakhtyari-and-damian-busz).